# Form validation if user leaves drop down populated with text

Tags: javascript

I have a page that I need to pop up an error message if the user leaves information in a box.

The user is selecting "Yes" from the Sale drop down and selecting a price (for example £10) from the New Product drop down. They are then changing the Sale drop down to "No" but leaving the price (£10) and this information is being submitted to the database.

How can I add code that warns the user that they have left the price (£10) when they have selected "No" in the Sale drop down?

```
<form name="test" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="POST">
          <table width="716">

    <input name="CallType2" type="hidden" id="CallType2" value="Unfulfilled Sales"/></td>
</tr><tr>
  <td style="text-align: left;">Mobile Number: </td>
  <td colspan="2" style="text-align: left;"><input name="MobileNumber" type="text" id="MobileNumber" maxlength="11" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td style="text-align: left;">Sale:</td>
  <td colspan="2" style="text-align: left;"><select name="Sale" id="Sale" onchange="display(this,'Yes','No');" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
  </select>  </td>
</tr>
<tbody id="Yes" style="display: none;">
      <tr>
        <td class="title"><div align="left">New Product:</div></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="field">
          <div align="left">
            <label>
                        <select name="SaleProduct" id="SaleProduct">
                                 <option value=""></option>
            <option value="£10">£10</option>
            <option value="£6.50">£6.50</option>


          </select>            </label>
          </div></td>
      </tr>

 <tr>
         </p>
        </div></td>
      </tr> 
          <tbody id="No" style="display: none;">
      <tr>
        <td class="title"><div align="left">Non Sale Reason:</div></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="field">
          <div align="left">
            <label>
                        <span style="text-align: left;">
                        <select name="CancelReason" id="CancelReason">
                          <option value=""></option>
                          <option value="Account changes incomplete">Account changes incomplete</option>
                          <option value="Customer Credit Rating">Customer Credit Rating</option>
                          <option value="Handset Ineligible Damaged">Handset Ineligible Damaged</option>
                          <option value="Handset Ineligible (Matrix)">Handset Ineligible (Matrix)</option>
                          <option value="Migration not yet complete">Migration not yet complete</option>
                          <option value="No transaction number">No transaction number</option>
              <option value="Insurance already on account">Insurance already on account</option>

                        </select>
                        </span></label>
          </div></td>
      </tr>  
    </tbody>


</tr>

        </tr>

<br>
    </tr>
          </table>


          <p>
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="test">
          <p align="center">
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>
</fieldset>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hpowe25j/

There is already a validateForm() running on submit to check that other boxes (that I have removed from this example) are not left blank

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think warning a user at that point is the right thing to do. They don't want to sale, why they should be getting a warning about the price. I think you should just remove the value in your validateForm function if Sale=No.

```
if(document.getElementById("Sale").value == undefined || document.getElementById("Sale").value == 'No')
    document.getElementById('SaleProduct').value = "";
```

Or, if you really want to warn the user, change your 'display' function triggered from the onchange event. add this to the code

```
if(document.getElementById("Sale").value == 'No' && document.getElementById('SaleProduct').value != '')
    alert('You should remove the price!'); // or make some div visible that contains the error message
```

You can also do this on validateForm.

Comment: That's good idea, I hadn't thought of that, thank you. Do I just add this code into the ValidateForm javascript? I tried it and it didn't work. Still submitted the price info when sales was selected "No"

Comment: Don't worry worked it out.Thank you so much, very helpful

Comment: I can't vote for the answer, as don't have high enough reputation

Comment: yeah just add it to valdateForm. it should submit the SaleProduct as an empty string. did it submit the price as something other than that?

Comment: Yeah I had a problem calling both functions so had to change the onsubmit. All sorted now, thank you again